How to parse custom data format in powerbi
I need to present some server stats provided by our it guys.
I asked JSON format, but unfortunately, while their input is wrapped in json, the actual data is presented like that:
"DiskInfo":  [
"@{DeviceID=C:; FreeSpaceGB=72.99; SizeGB=149.9; VolumeName=System}",
"@{DeviceID=D:; FreeSpaceGB=102; SizeGB=150; VolumeName=Programs}",
"@{DeviceID=E:; FreeSpaceGB=107.79; SizeGB=300; VolumeName=SQL Database}",
"@{DeviceID=L:; FreeSpaceGB=10.26; SizeGB=20; VolumeName=SQL Logs}",
"@{DeviceID=P:; FreeSpaceGB=462.34; SizeGB=1500; VolumeName=Repository}"
]

I know, I could split the data by ; then again by =, remove the extra columns and rename the value columns, but I hope there's a more clever way of doing this and there is a generic method of parsing these records.
